# Jupyter is not working

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I have problem with running Jupyter notebook. Recently I updated my Python to 3.7.0 version. Can be problem with that? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this post [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435) Trying following things may work:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```

Also if you can look at the stack trace it is referring to python3.6 path so may be python upgrade is an issue.

Comment: I can't even install Jupyter via pip now. I don't know what is going on. I think that python 3.7.0 does not support pyzmq ..